# ngOnInIt and array sorting in angular 6 application

Tags: angular6

I have angular 6 application, there in I have below code as per angular project.

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.LoadList("user");
      this.listName.sort((a:any,b:any) => {
        return a.name < b.name;
      })
     return this.listName;
  }
    onFocus() {
      this.showSearchResult = true;
    }
    LoadList(listType:string) {
      this.myService.dataList(listType).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(data.users)
        this.response=data.users.;
        if(this.response)  {
          for(let data of this.response) {
            this.listName.push({name: data.name, description:data.description})
           }
        }

        this.ref.detectChanges(); 
      });
```

Here you see that list is not getting alphabetically sroted (ascending), please help me

Comment: somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

Your `loadList` method calls a service, which I think is asynchronous. So you have to do something like this for sorting (see sortList function)

Also take a note that, while sorting strings, to do lowercase is necessary, as capital letters may return unnecessary result

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.LoadList("user");
}
  
sortList() {
  this.listName.sort((a,b) => {
    const nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
    const nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();

    if (nameA  < nameB) return -1;
 if(nameA  > nameB) return 1;
 return 0;
  })
}

onFocus() {
  this.showSearchResult = true;
}

LoadList(listType:string) {
        this.myService.dataList(listType).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(data.users)
        this.response=data.users.;
        if(this.response)  {
          for(let data of this.response) {
            this.listName.push({name: data.name, description:data.description})
           }
           
           this.sortList();
        }

        this.ref.detectChanges(); 
});
```

I don't know about your actual code, but the code above results the ascending order check this

```js
var list = [{id: 10, name:'kenny'}, {id:20, name: 'abhi'}, {id: 30, name: 'c'}, {id: 40, name: 'ka'}, {id: 40, name: 'abha'}]

list.sort((a,b) => {
    const nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
    const nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();

    if (nameA  < nameB) return -1;
    if(nameA  > nameB) return 1;
    return 0;
})

console.log(list)
```

Comment: thanks but I just want ascending order (a-z), above still gives me same result

Comment: dont function need to return list again like return this.listName ? becaues it will binded to HTML

Comment: I consoled like you, it gives me sorted array but in fact in hTML it does not why ? do you know ?  <li *ngFor="let c of listName ; let i = index;" class="advance-list-heading" >

Comment: @kelly this works sorry it was my mistake to refer wrong variable.